# How to unit test ViewComponent.Invoke()?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

In `ViewComponent` object, `HttpContext` and `User` are read-only properties.

How to unit test such a component?

I'm using the MSTest Freamwork.

The follow properties are used in my code

1. Cookie
2. Session
3. User(System.Security.Principal)

---

```
public ViewViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
    var vm = new SummaryViewModel();
    if (User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity && identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        vm.IsAuthenticated = true;
        vm.UserName = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "UserName").Value;
        vm.PhotoUrl = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "FacePicture").Value;
    }
    return View(vm);
}

[TestMethod]
public void UserSummaryVcTest()
{
    var component = new UserSummaryViewComponent();
    var model = component.Invoke().ViewData.Model as SummaryViewModel;
    Assert.AreEqual("UserName", model.UserName);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to source code the `ViewComponent` relies on the `ViewComponentContext.ViewContext` to expose those read only properties, Which in turn accesses the `HttpContext`. That is your entry point to mock the desired values.

```
[TestMethod]
public void UserSummaryVcTest() {

    // Arrange
    var expected = "Username value";
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(); //You can also Mock this
    //...then set user and other required properties on the httpContext as needed

    var viewContext = new ViewContext();
    viewContext.HttpContext = httpContext;
    var viewComponentContext = new ViewComponentContext();
    viewComponentContext.ViewContext = viewContext;

    var viewComponent = new UserSummaryViewComponent();
    viewComponent.ViewComponentContext = viewComponentContext;

    //Act
    var model = viewComponent.Invoke().ViewData.Model as SummaryViewModel;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, model.UserName);
}
```

Comment: I think the data type of invoke result can be asserted, something like : `Assert.IsType<SummaryViewModel>(result.ViewData.Model);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is just a samle for async,

```
    [TestMethod]
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task InvokeAsyncNameAsync()
{
# setup mocks
...
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
            var viewContext = new ViewContext();
            viewContext.HttpContext = httpContext;
            var viewComponentContext = new ViewComponentContext();
            viewComponentContext.ViewContext = viewContext;

            var footerComponent = CreateComponentInstance();
            footerComponent.ViewComponentContext = viewComponentContext;

            ViewViewComponentResult result = await footerComponent.InvokeAsync() as ViewViewComponentResult;
            FooterModel resultModel = (FooterModel)result.ViewData.Model;

....
# do your asserts verifications

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedTest, resultModel.FooterText);
}
```