# Why Does the ViewComponentResult.ExecuteResult method return void?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm trying to better understand the "behind the scenes" on view components.  I know that the standard approach is to invoke the `ViewComponent` by using

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("MyViewComponent", itsModel)
```

or a view component tag helper in the .cshtml file.

It's possible however to use view componets other ways.  So for example you can return a view directly from a controller by using `return ViewComponent("MyViewComponent", itsModel);` from an action method.

It seems like it should be possible to easily render the view component to a string.  I see that on the `ViewComponetResult` returned by `ViewComponent("MyViewComponent", itsModel);` there is an `ExecuteResult` method.

In a controller it can be called like this:

```
 ViewComponent("MyViewComponent", itsModel).ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
```

At first blush I'd expect such a method to return a string of html.  But it returns void.  Why?  What is `ViewComponentResult.ExecuteResult` doing if it's not returning a result?  And how can I render a `ViewComponentResult` into a string of HTML?

Comment: I don't have the exact answer here, but generally the string is the result of a stream writer, so that is what I would assume you need to pass the component through.

Comment: @TravisJ - That seems like a good clue but I'm struggling to figure out how to get a `ViewComponentResult` connected to a `StreamWriter`  I thought maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174028/how-to-unit-test-viewcomponent-invoke would help me but a `ViewComponent` no longer appears to have an `Invoke` method. Hmm.

Comment: I think it will be the solution. At least was the solution for me.
https://gist.github.com/pauldotknopf/b424e9b8b03d31d67f3cce59f09ab17f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understand how this works.  @TavisJ's comment is what tipped me of and sent me researching in the right direction.

On a `ViewComponentResult` or more universally, on *any* `ActionResult` the `ExecuteResult` returns void because the output of the `ViewComponent` is written to the associated `HttpResponse.Body`.  This is true of the async version of the call as well except that of course it returns a Task.

So for example, if a person were to make the following call:

```
  await ViewComponent("MyViewComponent", itsModel).ExecuteResultAsync(this.ControllerContext);
```

to capture the "output" of the view component, one would first need to replace the `this.ControllerContext.HttpResponse.Response.Body` with a stream of their choice before making the `ExecuteResultAsync` call so that the output is captured in a stream that can then be converted to a string.

Then of course, the original stream should be put back on the `this.ControllerContext.HttpResponse.Response.Body` so the rest of the view renders correctly.