# RouteData Property Duplicated

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I noticed in ASP.NET Core 2.2, we have access to get/set the `RouteData` from a `ViewComponent` using the following:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent.ViewComponentContext.ViewContext.RouteData
```

What is the point of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent.RouteData` when all this does is return the exact same data as `ViewContext.RouteData`?

Answer (score 0):

The two method return the same data when you use them in viewComponent.cs,from their definitions, you could see that only `ViewComponentContext.ViewContext.RouteData` could be used for unit test while `ViewComponent.RouteData` is read-only.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent.ViewComponentContext.ViewContext.RouteData:

```
 //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteData for the current request.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     The property setter is provided for unit test purposes only.
    public RouteData RouteData { get; set; }
```

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent.RouteData:(Read-only)

```
 //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent.RouteData for the current request.
    public RouteData RouteData { get; }
```

Not only for `RouteData`, but other properties like `HttpContext` also have the same configuration. `ViewComponent` relies on the `ViewComponentContext.ViewContext` to expose those read only properties.

Refer to 
[How to unit test ViewComponent.Invoke()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174028/how-to-unit-test-viewcomponent-invoke)

Comment: I still don't get why you can't do away with public RouteData RouteData { get; } and just use the public RouteData RouteData { get; set; } instead? It might be for unit testing but it also works perfectly well for non unit testing.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave I think both of them could get the route data but unit tests provides the view component with routing data through the `ViewComponentContext` property,which is how view components receives all context data.For non-unittesing scenario,it is more simple to use `ViewComponent.RouteData`.

Comment: https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=iEQWDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=what+is+difference+of+.ViewComponent.RouteData+and+ViewComponentContext.ViewContext.RouteData&source=bl&ots=tKYOeqF4hj&sig=ACfU3U0PyhUJqgxi7wrxtiRprTcloYMlNw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin8rzP45_kAhWSHqYKHXiFBZwQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=ViewComponentContext&f=false

Comment: It's exactly because of that page of that book that I wrote this question :)